# Mentioning staying at the airport overnight, can I get my Schengen visa application refused?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

I know that what is done is done, but just want to assure myself.

I submitted my Schengen visa in Spanish consulate in London today. The officer ask me about one night that I didn't have an accommodation.

I am flying from London to Athens at 23:59 on 11th October (yes, Athens, this is a part of my trip) and mentioning in my application that I will stay at the airport to wait for an early flight (at 7:00 day 12th Oct). The officer looks hesitant, what worries me.

Does anyone have experience about this? Please tell me if I should be fine. I just want to be honest. Will that cost me?

Comment: Have you checked that the Athens airport is actually open all night?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. Yes, I did some search and find that quite many people stay over at Athens airport. Lots of cheap flight come late and go early. So it is kind of a transit there (if I don't separate my travel, I would have bought a ticket from London to Santorini that includes an overnight transit at the airport. So I believe that people can say there.

Comment: Ironically, he was hesitant because he has the same question you do.  But that's a guess only.  It will not draw a refusal in its own right though

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did t think that would be problem until I saw his reaction (he said that would be fine but he is not the person who decides). I did have a Schengen visa before which I followed my itinerary so hopefully that is a plus. I am just note sure I how would they handle my situation. Please if you have any more information, please let me know. Can't wait until I have my passport back (he said it might take 4 weeks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with this particular scenario and can't tell you exactly how this particular Spanish consulate will treat your application but in theory it should not be an issue.

As far as the regulations are concerned, you should have a legitimate purpose and the *financial means* to pay for your accommodation, nothing more. There is absolutely no obligation to have each and every night accounted for and technically, you don't even need any specific booking or reservation, although it can be useful to support your application.

---

Your other question suggests you applied for a visa for a longer, more complex trip. If you do get a multiple-entry or two-entry visas from October 1st to the end of your trip to Greece, it would also allow you to enter on the 11th so the whole issue is moot (there is no such thing as a visa valid for one entry on the 1st and one entry on the 12th, it's either a single-entry visa or two entries at any time during the period of validity).

Since you are, as far as I can tell, a UK resident with a good profile, my guess is that you will get a multiple-entry with enough flexibility not to worry about this. But even if you don't, you would still have the option of shortening the trip at the other end (returning to the UK one day earlier to avoid going over the maximum stay limit).

Comment: I submitted my bank statement and saving account (which accumulate to about £7000 for 24 days) so I think my financial proof suffices. For your last sentence, the officer there was quite strict on our specific booking. For example, I have one night travelling by bus and he asked for the night bus ticket (which I had). That is why I feel quite worried about my situation. Technically, the arrival time is 23:59 but after those customs, I will set foots on Athens on 12th not 11th anymore. So I am hoping that they won't count. Arggggghhh, really worried. Thanks for your comments anyway!!

Comment: @Thien Greece is part of Schengen so you will clear immigration there. If your flight arrives early, you will do so on the 11th rather than the 12th. So you will need to account for that day in your visa application, even if you end up being late and arriving officially on the 12th.

Comment: Hi Michael. I think I might write my situation unclearly. The flight will arrive in Athens at 23:59, so basically it is 12th already. Yes now I am worried about the case if the flight arrive earlier than expectation. If it is the case, do you know if the consulate will refuse my visa right away, or they will send my application back for additional information (that I will have a chance to book for a night in Athens). Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi! I got an email saying my application is ready to collect. So basically 2 business days (29, 30) and I've got the result. I can't collect just yet as it is weekend now. Will see what happen on Monday. It will be my longest weekend. Do you think I definitely get refused? How come they would grant a visa just after two days :'(. Probably I will need another thread to ask how can I improve my application.

Comment: @Thien How did it turn out?

Comment: @Relaxed I couldn't go to the Embassy last week because I've caught up with my coursework and meetings. Just went and collected it today and still on my way back from London haha (it is 1:30am now). I got the visa, yes. But it is really short. The worst case as you predicted happened. I got 2 entries for 25 days. Just enough. My friend got one single and 13 days (he is having a 1 year well-paid internship and still 2 years more in his student visa). Probably we will not do our schengen visa via Spanish consulate again.

Comment: @Relaxed Thank you very much for asking and your tips/talking. I was definitely feeling better. Thank you. Really appreciate.